# C++ concurrency: Variable visibility outside of mutexes

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm having some trouble understanding when variables are forced to be written to memory, even outside of mutex blocks. I apologize for the convoluted code below, because I have stripped away logic that deals with whether `reader` decides if some data is stale. The important thing to note is that 99.9% of the time, readers will take the `fast path` and synchronization must be very fast, which is why I use an atomic `int32` to communicate both staleness and whether the slow path is now necessary.

I have the following setup, which I am "fairly" certain is race-free:

```
#define NUM_READERS 10

BigObject               mSharedObject;
std::atomic_int32_t     mStamp = 1;
std::mutex              mMutex;
std::condition_variable mCondition;
int32_t                 mWaitingReaders = 0;

void reader() {
    for (;;) { // thread loop
        for (;;) { // spin until stamp is acceptible
            int32_t stamp = mStamp.load();
            if (stamp > 0) { // fast path
                if (stampIsAcceptible(stamp) && 
                    mStamp.compare_exchange_weak(stamp, stamp + 1)) {
                    break;
                }
            } else { // slow path
                // tell the loader (writer) that we're halted
                std::unique_lock<mutex> lk(mMutex);
                mWaitingReaders++;
                mCondition.notify_all();
                while (mWaitingReaders != 0) {
                    mCondition.wait(lk);
                } // ###
                lk.unlock();
                // *** THIS IS WHERE loader's CHANGES TO mSharedObject
                // *** MUST BE VISIBLE TO THIS THREAD!
            }
        }
        // stamp acceptible; mSharedObject guaranteed not written to

        mSharedObject.accessAndDoFunStuff();

        mStamp.fetch_sub(1); // part of hidden staleness logic
    }
}

void loader() {
    for (;;) { // thread loop
        // spin until we somehow decide we want to change mSharedObject!
        while (meIsHappySleeping()) {}

        // we want to modify mSharedObject, so set mStamp to 0 and wait
        // for readers to see this and report that they are now waiting
        int32_t oldStamp = mStamp.exchange(0);
        unique_lock<mutex> lk(mMutex);
        while (mWaitingReaders != NUM_READERS) {
            mCondition.wait(lk);
        }
        // all readers are waiting. start writing to mSharedObject
        mSharedObject.loadFromFile("example.foo");
        mStamp.store(oldStamp);
        mWaitingReaders = 0; // report completion
        lk.unlock();
        mCondition.notify_all();
        // *** NOW loader's CHANGES TO mSharedObject
        // *** MUST BE VISIBLE TO THE READER THREADS!
    }
}

void setup() {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_READERS; i++) {
        std::thread t(reader); t.detach();
    }
    std::thead t(loader); t.detach();
}
```

The parts marked in stars `***` are what concerns me. This is because while my code excludes races (as far as I can see), `mSharedObject` is only protected by a mutex while being written to by `loader()`. Because `reader()` needs to be extremely fast (as noted above), I do not want its read-only accesses to `mSharedObject` to have to be protected by a mutex.

One "guaranteed" solution is to introduce a thread-local variable `const BigObject *latestObject` at line `###`, which is set to `&mSharedObject` and then use that for access. But is this bad practice? And is it really necessary? Will the atomic operations / mutex release operations guarantee that readers see the changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Lock-free code, and even locking code using just atomics is far from simple. The first thing to do would be to just add a mutex and profile how much of the performance is actually lost in the synchronisation. Note that current implementations of mutex may just do a quick spin-lock, which is roughly an atomic operation when uncontended.

If you want to attempt lock-free programming you will need to look into the memory ordering arguments to atomic operations. The writer will need to `..._release` to synchronise with a reader doing `..._acquire` (or use sequential consistency in both sides). Otherwise the reads/writes to any other variables may not be visible.

Comment: Yes, I've spent hours of research on this and got me nowhere... I even made a little meme about it: http://imgur.com/a/Dpx46
Right now all my atomic operations are the default sequential consistency. Does that make a difference to your answer?

Comment: I just noticed something else. After reader's `***` segment, it will loop back, sequentially consistently access `mStamp` before calling `mSharedObject.accessAndDoFunStuff()`. But `mStamp` is seq-con written to by `loader()` right after `loadFromFile()`. This feels like it should be enough to force `reader()` to see the change to `mSharedObject`. Am I right? Thanks!!