# C++ concurrency: conditional atomic operations?

Tags: c++, multithreading

This question is related to this question, but I've decided to simplify this one so that it's easier to answer. [C++ concurrency: Variable visibility outside of mutexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908634/c-concurrency-variable-visibility-outside-of-mutexes)

Suppose I have the following setup. There are an arbitrary number of `reader`s, and only 1 `loader`. You can assume the following things about this code:

- `(*)` and `(**)` are RW race-free (but not necessarily through a common mutex). In other words, I guarantee through synchro code not shown below that, if `(**)` writes, then all readers are guaranteed to be spinning in the "synchro loop". Note, however, that multiple readers may read at once.
- `(1)` through `(5)` could be anything - synchro with other objects, conditions, waiting, reading `mAtomic` etc, *except* code that could cause `loader` to race its write with a `reader`.

...

```
atomic_int32_t mAtomic = 1;
BigObject      mShared;

void reader() {
    for (;;) { // thread loop
        for (;;) { // synchro loop
            // (1)
            if (mAtomic.compare_exchange_weak(expect, desired)) // seq-con
                break;
            // (2)
        }
        mShared.readOnlyHeavyComputations(); // (*)
    }
}

void loader() {
    for (;;) { // thread loop
        while (planetsAreAligned()); // spin until whenever
        // (3)
        int32_t old = mAtomic.exchange(valReaderWontExpect); // seq-con
        // (4)
        mShared.loadFromFile("example.foo"); // (**)
        mAtomic.store(old); // seq-con
        // (5)
    }
}
```

My question is now rather simple. No matter what happens at lines `(1)`, `(2)`, `(3)`, `(4)` and `(5)` (but as the assumption above), will the write at `(**)` **always become visible** to the readers at `(*)`?

Under my understanding of sequential consistent atomics, the answer is yes - because directly after `(**)`, `mAtomic` is stored to - which is observed (`compare_exchange_weak`) by a `reader()` before exiting its synchro loop. Under my understanding of the C++ standard, this ordering of atomics ensures all effects by the loader must be seen by the reader. Am I correct?

Comment: What in your algorithm prevents `mAtomic.compare_exchange_weak` to succeed with original value of atomic, *before* `mAtomic.exchange` is executed?

Comment: Nothing. However, at `(4)`, the algorithm uses `condition_variable` to wait for all readers to start spinning (at `(1)`). Once all are spinning, `loadFromFile` can be safely called because no readers are reading. Does that make sense? If it's still unsafe, I'd love to hear.